# Can't identify if tableView parameter is seachResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchresultscontroller

I'm developing an iOS 6 application.

I want to add a search functionallity to a `UITableView` following this [Table Search](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) example from Apple. But, my implementation doesn't work.

On `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I don't know how to if `tableView` parameter is `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`.

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, `tableView` is a `UISearchResultsTableView`, but this line:

```
if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
```

It is always false.

Maybe, I need to add an outlet to access `seachResultsTableView`, but I haven't found that outlet on [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

This `ViewController.h`:

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {
```

**What do I need to do to make it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(searching) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [searchedListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else {

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
}

return cell;
```

if all you're trying to achieve is a normal search then use this.